# How do i generate cookie like in postman temporary header

Tags: curl, postman

I have cUrl in PHP but when I execute it, it needed some cookie to be able to use the cUrl when i run it in postman and get the cookie from temporary headers and copy it in my cUrl in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` it loads and it response what i want.

here is the screenshot i need from postman

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

how do i get that in order to run my cUrl in PHP